# Создание и проверка набора карт

Tags: java

Всем привет. Помогите с задачей.
Сначала попросите пользователя ввести нужное количество карточек. Затем попросите ввести термин и определение каждой карточки. Спросите обо всех новых словах, которые он ввел. Программа должна дать термин и попросить дать определение.

Вопрос. Как отработать второй for до начала запуска третьего for? При этом в третьем нужен j. Почему equals не сравнивает?

```
Пример вывода:
Input the number of cards:
> 2
The card #1:
> black
The definition of the card #1:
> white
The card #2:
> white
The definition of the card #2:
> black
Print the definition of "black":
> white
Correct answer.
Print the definition of "white":
> blue
Wrong answer. The correct one is "black".
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MakeItYourOwn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the number of cards:");
        int size = scanner.nextInt(); // Read the size of the array from the keyboard and write to "size"
        String[] arr = new String[size]; // Create an int array of size "size"
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("The card #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            arr[i] = scanner.next();// fill the array color card with the keyboard
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("The definition of the card #" + (i + 1) + ":");
                arr[j] = scanner.next();// fill the array definition card with the keyboard
             for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
                    System.out.println("Print the definition of \"" + (arr[j]) + "\":");
                    arr[k] = scanner.next();// fill the array definition card with the keyboard
                    if (arr[j].equals(arr[k])) {
                        System.out.println("Correct answer.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Wrong answer. The correct one is \"" + (arr[j]) + "\".");
                    }break;
                }break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал через Map. Как оптимизировать решение?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> color = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the number of cards:");
    // Read the size of the array from the keyboard and write to "size"
    int size = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    // Create an int array of size "size"
    String[] arr = new String[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("The card #" + (i + 1) + ":");
        // fill the array color card with the keyboard
        String a = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The definition of the card #" + (i + 1) + ":");
        // fill the array definition card with the keyboard
        String b = scanner.nextLine();
        color.put(a, b);
    }
    for (Map.Entry m : color.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Print the definition of \"" + (m.getKey()) + "\":");
        if (scanner.nextLine().equals(m.getValue())) {
            System.out.println("Correct answer.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong answer. The correct one is \"" + (m.getValue()) + "\".");
        }
    }
}
```